# How to replace all dp value such as 50dp with a @dimen/50_dp at once?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have got lots of XML files in which margin and padding dimensions are hardcode I have to replace all of them in format @denem/margin_20 ....etc
[image]

I have made dimens and saved all the values I need. But I have lots of XML files it will take a lot of time for me to go and change one by one file manually
[image]
SO I want to ask is there any trick to change all the values at once in Android Studio.

Thanks a lot for Helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R` to replace and write `"50dp"` with inverted commas in find field . Then in replace field write `@dimen/_50dp`. Replace one occurrence and if it worked as expected and replace all other occurrences.

NOTE: if you want to change this in just `res` folder then you can select this folder only in find and replace dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The approved answer is good but then you will have to do it one by one for each dimension so you can do the following:

1. Press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`R` to replace all.
2. Select layout Directory by selecting "Directory" Option
3. Select Regrex ".*" from right side of find text input
4. in find first write (?!")\d\d(?=dp")
5. in replace write @dimen/_$0
6. Then click replace all
7. do similar thing for (?!")\d(?=dp")

It will replace all 2 digits and 1 digit dp values to dimension. You will manually need to edit negative and floating dp values.